# SQL query runs in database, but in PHP says "undefined index"

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(german),"DEFAULT") from translate_content WHERE english = :englishContent0 UNION ALL
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(german),"DEFAULT") from translate_content WHERE english = :englishContent1 UNION ALL
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(german),"DEFAULT") from translate_content WHERE english = :englishContent2
```

With the idea that if a value is not found then it will return the value "DEFAULT".  My problem is that this query works fine when I run it directly in the database, but when I try it in PHP I get an error saying "undefined index: "german".

I am using MySQL and PHP 5.5.11.  I'm sorry if this isn't enough information, but I don't know what else to provide (but ask and I will deliver!)

I should probably state that the column "german" definitely does exist in the table "translate_content", and I have tried encapsulating the column names in back ticks.  The problem only seems to arise when I use the COALESCE function, but I'm at a loss as to how it can work when I copy and paste it into the database, but not when I run it directly from PHP :/

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Show us the code where you execute the queries (the php code).

Comment: You probably need to use `as <column alias>` to give the column a name that can then be referenced in PHP.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - thank you!  I knew it must be something trivial, but of course it's only obvious once you know it.  Thanks for the fast reply :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a column alias like

`SELECT COALESCE(MAX(german),"DEFAULT") AS Column1`

BTW, your query can be modified using a `IN` operator like below and no need of using `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(german),"DEFAULT") AS some_column
from translate_content WHERE english IN (:englishContent0,:englishContent1,:englishContent2)
```

Comment: Thanks - I have just tried this thanks to Gordon's suggestion and it works :)  I actually can't use IN in this instance due to the way the queries are generated, but thanks for the tip!